# How to plot and indicator (ema) from different timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
study(title="Moving Average 400", shorttitle="EMA 400", overlay=true)
len400 = input(400, minval=1, title="EMA - 400")
src400 = input(close, title="Source")
out400 = ema(src400, len400)
plot(out400, title="EMA - 400", color=#9b9e9e, linewidth=4)
```

I am trying to paint EMA 400 on 1H or 4H timeframes but I want calculate value always from daily close. I am not sure how to do it because right now the line is painted on different levels when I change the timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `security()` function. Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) for more information.

Since you already calculate the ema400, you can just pass that variable as `expression` parameter.

```
ema400_daily = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", out400, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```